# Counter Up JQuery counting to random numbers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a counter up on this section that works perfectly the first time I open the page. The problem is when I go back to the top and come back to the section the counter stops at a random number.

I want that no matter how many times I scroll up or down and come back to the section it counts up to the same numbers

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 500,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row g-4 mb-4">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-start border-5 border-primary px-3">
      <h1 class="about-numbers counter">10</h1>
      <div class="ps-4">
        <p class="mb-0 about-text">Years of</p>
        <h6 class="text-uppercase mb-0 about-bold">Experience</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-start border-5 border-primary px-3">
      <h1 class="about-numbers">+</h1>
      <h1 class="about-numbers counter">5000</h1>
      <div class="ps-4">
        <p class="mb-0 about-text">Products</p>
        <h6 class="text-uppercase mb-0 about-bold">Sold</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(...).counterUp is not a function`

Comment: I'm using this libraries
 <!-- JQuery Script -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.7.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <!-- Counter Up Script -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js" integrity="sha512-d8F1J2kyiRowBB/8/pAWsqUl0wSEOkG5KATkVV4slfblq9VRQ6MyDZVxWl2tWd+mPhuCbpTB4M7uU/x9FlgQ9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

That should work

Comment: @CamiloAgudelo you should add that to the code in your question, not as a comment.

Comment: The documentation of Counter-Up says that you should use [Counter-Up 2](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2)

Answer (score 0):

Using counterUp 2 per docs, here is a modified answer from the official docs that doesn't use waypoints.

[Official Docs](https://github.com/bfintal/Counter-Up2)

[Official Codepen](https://codepen.io/bfintal/pen/zYzOGpZ)

My modification loops through the counter elements and also I added an else statement to remove the is-visible class to allow it to restart.

```js
const counterUp = window.counterUp.default

const callback = entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    const el = entry.target
    if (entry.isIntersecting && !el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
      counterUp(el, {
        duration: 500,
        delay: 10,
      })
      el.classList.add('is-visible')
    } else {
      el.classList.remove('is-visible')
    }
  })
}

const IO = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  threshold: 1
})

const els = document.querySelectorAll('.counter')
els.forEach((el) => {IO.observe(el)})
```

```css
.row{height:1000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/counterup2@2.0.2/dist/index.js">
</script>
<div class="row g-4 mb-4">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-start border-5 border-primary px-3">
      <h1 class="about-numbers counter">10</h1>
      <div class="ps-4">
        <p class="mb-0 about-text">Years of</p>
        <h6 class="text-uppercase mb-0 about-bold">Experience</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center border-start border-5 border-primary px-3">
      <h1 class="about-numbers">+</h1>
      <h1 class="about-numbers counter">5000</h1>
      <div class="ps-4">
        <p class="mb-0 about-text">Products</p>
        <h6 class="text-uppercase mb-0 about-bold">Sold</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```